# intel compiler buggy remarks for variadic templates?

Tags: c++, intel, compiler-warnings, variadic-templates, icc

I use intel compiler, and since intel doesn't really support -Wall I use -Wremarks for warnings...

I have this simple code which just makes a certain object..

```
    template<typename... Args_t>
    static inline Obj makeObj(Args_t&&... args) {
        auto obj = std::make_shared<Obj>(args...); // probably can forward but doesn't matter..
        return obj;
    }
```

I get this remark:

```
remark #869: parameter "args" was never referenced
```

is this a bug? anyone seen this?

Comment: Are you sure that your compiler is C++11 compliant (with the compiler flags that you are using)?

Comment: yes, since it works.

Comment: Where does the compiler get information about Obj ? It's not part of your template. Not just that. Your return type is Obj and you are returning a shared_ptr<Obj>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a bugged warning [that was already reported in the Intel forum](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/345355). It doesn't have any particular meaning as the code is completely okay (although you should consider perfect forwarding).

Answer (score 0):

If you are kept with intel compiler version 15, I found the following workaround. Perhaps it works for you aswell

```
template<typename... Args_t>
static inline Obj makeObj(Args_t&&... args) {
    [&args...]{}(); // WORKAROUND 
    // ... your other code
    return obj;
}
```

Only the lambda did work it around. Apparently lamdba captures of packs actually use the parameter pack. But expanding the pack otherwise will not "use" the pack the same way.